# Visual Studio 11 Beta and Windows 8 Consumer Preview startup problems on clean install

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, beta, visual-studio-2012

I've installed the following on a VMWare Player virtual machine:

- Windows 8 Consumer Preview (x86)
- Visual Studio 11 Beta Professional (from ISO image), from MSDN

I haven't installed anything else on the VM. The account I've logged in is a Windows Live account.

After starting Visual Studio, I get the following error (not immediately after startup, but soon after):

[image]

After that, when I try to create a new project I get the following error message:

[image]

Note that I've tried to make it as clean install as possible.
I have checked the SHA-1 checksums of the ISO-files. They match.
There is enough memory and HDD space.

UPDATE: It is worth to mention that both the Windows 8 and Visual Studio setups ran fine without any errors.

Comment: I would recommend asking this question on the [Visual Studio Setup and Installation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/threads) forum on MSDN.  You are likely to get a better, faster response there.  [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/vssetup/thread/41f50aa4-c855-4214-be6d-4a2edef3c390) looks like the same issue you are having.

Comment: In fact I have: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/d892ea71-8562-410c-919c-cc832079bf84/#d892ea71-8562-410c-919c-cc832079bf84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve this problem. Instead I installed the same setup on actual PC and everything works pretty much ok. Conclusion: the configuration is not compatible with VMWare Player.